# Algorithm to Calculate the path of a parabola utilizing a 2 axis movement

Tags: algorithm

With regard to the attached image, I need to have a calculation Algorithm to move Axis A down n inches, and Axis B Left to right m inches in order for component circle D to follow the curve of the parabola; circle D is not always 10 inches and can be smaller. I am not a math major so this is a bit more complicated for me. I know I have an Arc length on Axis A which must be calculated (I don't know how to do this.), I then have an Arc Length on Axis B as well and that the arc is moving in reference to the position of Axis A , this arc length associated with Diameter of Circle D will determine where on the parabola the point of intersection between Circle D and the Parabola is . In order to follow the curve of the parabola starting from left to right or vice versa - I need a formula to follow the parabola. Accounting for D changing size.  Can somebody provide some answers as to how to do this ; a nice formula with some explanatory information - at least enough detail that I can do a search on those parts and bits to get an understanding of what to do.

[image: 2 Axis With Circle to follow Path of Parabola]

[I have looked and found some information that may be helpful to me but does not answer my question at all:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039039/fastest-way-to-fit-a-parabola-to-set-of-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039039/fastest-way-to-fit-a-parabola-to-set-of-points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to calculate the curve resulting as an offset of a parabola.

In the C++ program that follows I'll show how to first find the formula of the parabola, then how to calculate the offset from that curve and finally how to find the angles which the two axis form to each other.

I consider point (0,0) as the left extreme of the parabola, the bottom of that (vertex) will be at the coordinates (12,-8.75), while the right extreme at (24,0). Take this picture as a reference (the parabola is blue, the trajectory of the center of the circle is orange):

[image]

Be aware that if the circle is too big, while it's tangent on one side it can intersect the parabola on the other side. I'm not sure if 12" is the total width of the parabola or only one half, but in the latter case a 10" tool will be too large:

[image]

The program will print out some samples (25) of the coordinates of the points where the circle representing the tool is tangent to the parabola, the corresponding coordinates of the center of the circle (the position of the tool) and the angles of the two axis (alpha and beta).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::setw;
using std::vector;

int main() {

    // set number of steps or points of approximation
    int n_steps = 25;

    // declare vectors to store coordinates into
    vector<double> x2(n_steps), y2(n_steps);

    // calculate the parameters of the parabola expressed by the formula 
    // y = ax^2 + bx + c
    // Knowing 2 points, one of which is the vertex.
    // xv = -b/2a               | b = -2axv   
    // y0 = ax0^2 + bx0 + c  => | yv - y0 = a(xv^2 - x0^2) + b(xv - x0)
    // yv = axv^2 + bxv + c     | yv - y0 = a(xv - x0)(xv + x0) + b(xv - x0)
    // 
    // a ((xv - x0)*(xv + x0) - 2xv(xv - x0)) = yv - y0
    // a (xv - x0)*(xv + x0 - 2xv) = yv - y0

    // Known coordinates
    double  xv = 12.0,
            yv = -8.75,
            x0 = 0.0,
            y0 = 0.0; 

    double  dx = xv - x0,
            a = (y0 - yv) / ( dx * dx ),
            b = - 2.0 * a * xv,
            c = y0 - x0 * ( a * x0 + b );

    cout << "Parabola formula:\n" 
         << "y = " << a << "x^2 + " << b << "x + " << c << "\n\n"
         << "max acceptable diameter: " << 1.0 / a << "\n\n";

    // Coordinates of rotating axes, extrapolated from your drawing
    double  r1 = 13,
            r2 = 9,
            x1 = xv - r1,
            y1 = r2;
    // some helper values (constant) I'll use later
    double  rad_to_deg = 180.0 / M_PI,
            r1quad = r1 * r1,
            r2quad = r2 * r2,
            rdif = r1quad - r2quad,
            rsum = r1quad + r2quad,
            rden = 1.0 / ( 2.0 * r1 * r2 );

    // radius of the circle (tool)
    double  diameter = 10,
            radius = diameter / 2.0;
    cout << "Diameter of tool (circle): " << diameter << "\n\n";


    // calculate parabola points
    cout << "\t\t\tTangent\t\t\t\tCenter of circle\t\t  alpha\t\tbeta\n";
    // xt[0] = x0    xt[n_steps] = x0 + 2*(xv - x0)
    double step = 2.0 * dx / ( n_steps - 1 );
    for ( int i = 0; i < n_steps; ++i ) {
        // calculate the tangent points which lies on the parabola
        double  xt = x0 + i * step,
                yt = xt * ( a * xt + b ) + c;

        // calculate the offset points, coordinates of the center of the circle
        // first derivative of the parabola
        double delta = 2.0 * a * xt + b;

        // point perpendicular to the tangent at distance equal to radius
        double k = radius / sqrt(delta * delta + 1.0);
        x2[i] = xt - k * delta;
        y2[i] = yt + k;

        // distance from x,y to x1,y1
        double  dx1 = x2[i] - x1,
                dy1 = y2[i] - y1,
                r3quad = dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1,
                r3 = sqrt(r3quad);

        // Now that I know the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle 
        // and the lengths of its sides I can calculate the inner angles
        // using Carnot teorem, for example: a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc*cos(alpha)
        double alpha_Carnot = acos((rdif + r3quad) / (2.0 * r1 * r3)),
                beta_Carnot = acos((rsum - r3quad) * rden);

        // angle to the orizzontal of line from x1,y1 to x,y in radians
        double  gamma = atan2(dy1,dx1);
        // angle of Axis A to the orizzontal in degrees
        double  alpha = (gamma + alpha_Carnot) * rad_to_deg;
        // angle of Axis B to Axis A. beta = 0 if parallel
        double  beta = beta_Carnot * rad_to_deg - 180.0;

        // output the coordinates
        cout << std::fixed << setw(4) << i << setw(10) << xt << setw(10) << yt
             << setw(15) << x2[i] << setw(10) << y2[i]
             << setw(15) << alpha << setw(12) << beta << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Parabola formula:
y = 0.0607639x^2 + -1.45833x + 0

max acceptable diameter: 16.4571

Diameter of tool (circle): 10

            Tangent             Center of circle          alpha     beta
   0  0.000000  0.000000       4.123644  2.827642      -7.228866 -142.502245
   1  1.000000 -1.397569       5.003741  1.597437      -7.151211 -132.856051
   2  2.000000 -2.673611       5.860925  0.503378      -7.962144 -123.965745
   3  3.000000 -3.828125       6.690144 -0.454279      -9.159057 -115.700562
   4  4.000000 -4.861111       7.485392 -1.276137     -10.496232 -108.022957
   5  5.000000 -5.772569       8.239777 -1.964178     -11.833367 -100.941141
   6  6.000000 -6.562500       8.945861 -2.522462     -13.081185  -94.488527
   7  7.000000 -7.230903       9.596439 -2.957906     -14.180211  -88.708034
   8  8.000000 -7.777778      10.185964 -3.280939     -15.093523  -83.633631
   9  9.000000 -8.203125      10.712644 -3.505588     -15.805504  -79.267662
  10 10.000000 -8.506944      11.180897 -3.648397     -16.321003  -75.558850
  11 11.000000 -8.689236      11.603201 -3.725755     -16.659970  -72.392050
  12 12.000000 -8.750000      12.000000 -3.750000     -16.845543  -69.600878
  13 13.000000 -8.689236      12.396799 -3.725755     -16.889440  -67.003199
  14 14.000000 -8.506944      12.819103 -3.648397     -16.782985  -64.443028
  15 15.000000 -8.203125      13.287356 -3.505588     -16.499460  -61.816277
  16 16.000000 -7.777778      13.814036 -3.280939     -16.005878  -59.069041
  17 17.000000 -7.230903      14.403561 -2.957906     -15.277444  -56.174060
  18 18.000000 -6.562500      15.054139 -2.522462     -14.309495  -53.098717
  19 19.000000 -5.772569      15.760223 -1.964178     -13.126180  -49.773973
  20 20.000000 -4.861111      16.514608 -1.276137     -11.788732  -46.064496
  21 21.000000 -3.828125      17.309856 -0.454279     -10.409278  -41.729113
  22 22.000000 -2.673611      18.139075  0.503378      -9.184425  -36.337384
  23 23.000000 -1.397569      18.996259  1.597437      -8.503984  -29.006402
  24 24.000000  0.000000      19.876356  2.827642      -9.577076  -16.878208
```

Those are some picture (thanks to excell) at different positions:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your points left {0,0} , vertex , right {24,0} matches what I am doing as well. 12 inches is the maximum width of the parabola, I need to rotate axis A down and then axis B to follow the path of the parabola. Given the circle diameter can change from a maximum of 10 inch to a minimum of 7 Inches. delta[Axis A], delta[Axis B ]  + (10 - delta[Circle Diameter]) = points on the path of parabola.  See second response as there was not enough room to complete here.

Comment: The two numbers for center of circle  I am not sure what the representation is; points along a line in inches from the tangent ? In your equations it looks like what I should be doing is positioning the center of the circle 1/2  circle diameter from the Tangent point; Your answer is helping me to frame the problem better and also define better how to achieve the desired result; namely rotating Axis A and Axis B to position the center of the Circle to 1/2 Diameter of the circle.This is not pitch black to me anymore, more like a full moon; maybe I can start to see the sun rise here. :-)

Comment: @StixO Angle calculation added, with some descriptive pictures. Tell me if it's OK.

Comment: @Bob__ which software or tool did you use to create and illustrate the mathematical drawings;) btw nice answer got my vote

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Excell ;).

Comment: @Bob__ hmm how can you draw thing and calculate in excel any reference to that, And we agree this is microsfot excel?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I used the same formulas of the program to calculate in a table all the coordinates, then for a specific row I added some points with labels, and calculate the points of the circle (center and radius are known)

Comment: @Bob__ I did know such was possible in excel need to rush it up. thank any how for feedback.

Comment: @Bob__ This looks good for me to get my head around - when I have time over the next couple of days, I should know if it works out as I expect. The Parabola is always 12 inch wide by 8.75 deep. The only vars is the movements of Axis[A & B] and also Diameter D. Your graphs and plots perfect to help me associate the math. I am thinking (and assume) that the  Alpha and Theta numbers are in degrees of rotation. I think all this helps me a great deal.!!  JIC I need to ask a question  I will mark as answer after I have had a chance to work it out.

Comment: This works as having the angles is the key to being able to move distance x to achieve angle alpha or angle beta.! Wish I could mark as answer twice! The Graphs and Plots are excellent and the nomenclature of how to achieve the result - carnot theorem (I never heard of it.) Thanks.

Comment: @Bob__ if I have a super ellipse with the predefined tangent points will this equation for finding the coordinates of x2,y2 the center of the circle and alpha, beta angles still be valid ?

Comment: @StixO as long as you can provide a formula to calculate the points of the curve and the tangent in that point, I think it could work. You have to check if the axes are long enough, at least.

Comment: @Bob__ I have the Cartesian values x,y of the 38 points on the curve of the super-ellipse - I was thinking to substitute these values into the xt,yt component of the formula //calculate offset, //point perpendicular - the points I have are exact from an engineering drawing.The axis are long enough -  I have a mock up of the assembly. I will try it to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a parabola `ax^2+bx+c` is `2ax+b`.

To find where the circle has a certain slope value (`s`), you have `y/x = s`. Together with the equation `x^2+y^2=r^2` (you probably want the lower half of the circle, btw), you can see where, relative to the center of the circle, the circle's edge will touch the parabola.

So if the distance between the circle center and the parabola point is different from the distance between the circle center and the tangent point, you need to move the axis.