# finding maximum of a function with least probes taken

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have some code, a function basically, that returns a value. This function takes long time to run. Function takes a double as a parameter:

```
double estimate(double factor);
```

My goal is to find such parameter factor at which this `estimate` function returns maximum value. I can simply brute force and iterate different factor inputs and get what I need, but the function takes long time to run, so I'd like to minimize amount of "probes" that I take (e.g. call the estimate function as least as possible).
Usually, maximum is returned for factor values between 0.5 and 3.5. If I graph returned values, I get something that looks like a bell curve. What's the most efficient approach to partition possible inputs to that I could discover maximum faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function indeed has a bell shaped curve then you can use binary search as follows:

Choose an initial x1 (say x1 = 2, midway between 0.5 and 3.5)  and find f(x1) and f(x1 + delta) where delta is small enough. If f(x1 + delta) > f(x1) it means that the peak is towards the right of x1 otherwise it is towards the left.

Carry out binary search and come to a close enough value of the peak as you want.

You can modify the above approach by choosing the next x_t according to the difference f(x1 + delta) - f(x1).

Comment: after drawing it on paper I came up to the same approach as you described.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer suggested a 2 point approach. This is a good idea for functions that are approximately lines, because lines are defined by 2 parameters: `y=ax+b`.

However, the actual bell-shaped curve is more like a parabola, which is defined by `ax²+bx+c` (so 3 parameters). You therefore should take 3 points `{x1,x2,x3}` and [solve for `{a,b,c}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24690401/15416). This will give you an estimate for the `xtop` at `-b/2a`. (The linked answer uses the name `x0` here).

You'll need to iteratively approximate the actual top if the function isn't a real parabola, but this process converges really fast. The easiest solution is to take the original triplet `x1,x2,x3`, add `xtop` and remove the `xn` value which is furthest away from `xtop`. The advantage of this is that you can reuse 2 of the old `f(x)` values. This reuse helps a lot with the stated goal of "mininal samples".